# Reading wrong characters from file Java

Tags: java

I am reading characters from file by skipping 2 times

```
     fis = new FileInputStream("C:/data/25130.in ");
     fis.skip(24305);//This position contains _(UnderScore)
     l=fis.read();
     fis.skip(24312);//This position also contains _(Underscore)
     i = fis.read();
     ch= (char)l;
     c = (char)i;
     System.out.print("Ch: "+ch);//Returns Underscore
     System.out.print("C: "+c); // Returns 9 instead of UnderScore
```

If i delete the fist skip like the following

```
     fis = new FileInputStream("C:/data/25130.in ");         
     fis.skip(24312);//This position also contains _(underscore)
     i = fis.read();
     c = (char)i;
     System.out.print("C: "+c); // Now it returns Underscore
```

I intend to read 2 characters at 2 positions..Where was the problem

Comment: Make sure you specify a character encoding.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the same file? The code fragments use different files.

Comment: I am sure .It is same file.Edited now

Comment: Are those positions exact position of underscores in the file, or the 2nd one is the position from the current position?

Comment: If you are reading a file at different positions you may want to consider using RandomAccessFile instead of FileStreams: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think FileInputStream.skip does not go to the given position, it skips the given number of bytes. So after your second skip you will end up at 48617, plus one more that you actually read.

Try 6 as parameter for your second skip.

Answer (score 2):

`fis.skip(24312)` skips that many characters (it reads 24312 bytes and throws them away....)

What you want to do is "position" the input stream, and throw away only (24312 - 24305) bytes, or `fis.skip(7)`

EDIT: hmmm, lutzh is right, you want to `fis.skip(6)` but....

what you really want to do is use a [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and use the seek(position) method...

Comment: Ya it works after changing second skip to fis.skip(6)

Comment: I have edited the answer to consider this.... you want a RandomAccessFile, but, additionally, skip is not the same as 'position', so you have to do the math yourself to skip the right amount.